# Squeeze theorem -multivariable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$ \lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} {\sqrt{|xy|}}$$

I want to show this limit equal to 0 to prove continuity. However, I am not sure how to squeeze it so that limit is equal to 0. Anyone can help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a thought. Putting $f(x,y):=\sqrt{|xy|}$ it is obvious that $(f(x,y))^2\to0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$. But this implies that $f(x,y)\to0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$|xy|\le \frac12 (x^2+y^2)$$

Thus, for any $\epsilon>0$,

$$\sqrt{|xy|}\le \frac12 (x^2+y^2)< \epsilon$$

whenever $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta = (2\epsilon)^{1/2}$.  And we are done!